# .NET Remoting Client Config File multiserver Object

Tags: .net, remoting, configuration-files

I'm in the middle of a crisis.

How can i register a object in configuration file multiple times?

Its simple i have server1, server2 and server3 that have the object (SomeObject) and i would like to do something like this on Clients configuration file:

```
<client>
    <wellknown type="IRemCalc.ICalc, IRemCalc"
            url="http://localhost:12234/RemoteCalc1.soap" />
    <wellknown type="IRemCalc.ICalc, IRemCalc"
    url="http://localhost:1234/RemoteCalc1.soap"/>
</client>
```

But it throws me an exception saying that i cant register the same object twice, any solutions?

This is for a school work and I'm dying here.

Comment: 1) To format XML or code, don't use HTML. Instead, just paste the XML or code, select it in the editor, then press Control-K. 2) It's interesting that your school has you working with obsolete technology. Remoting has been replaced with WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Remoting is obsolete now, and I haven't used it for many years. Still, if I remember correctly, you in fact *cannot* register the same type multiple times.

Registering a type makes sure that when you use "`new type()`" in your code, it will create a remoting proxy instead of the actual type. That proxy will naturally address a single remote server.

If you need to use multiple servers, then you'll have to "manually" create proxy instances. As I said, I haven't used Remoting since about 2004, so I don't remember the API for manually creating a proxy.

Comment: Thakz for the help, but this question is from a work that i have to do to college, i know that is obsolete but my teechers still live in the past what i have to do...
The questions simples says that without changing any code, configure the client configuration file so that is possible to use 3 servers for some object insted of one . . .

Comment: @Trent: obviously impossible without changing code. Consider: what would change to make it use server 2 instead of server 1? Magic?

Comment: in execution time is easy, just get the proxy by Activator.getInstance with different urls but in the config files just dont know

Comment: @Trent: there is no way to do it with configuration and with no code change.